# Create new worksheets based on row data values

Tags: c#, excel, for-loop, export, epplus

I have a data set that I want to split into specific worksheets based on row values and export via my C# web app.

Data columns (example): 
`SerialNumber`, `ProductType`, `Location`, `Date`

I need to loop through the record set sorted by column `Location` and then detect when that `Location` value changes so I can create a new worksheet and put data for each distinct `Location` in separate tabs/worksheets.

I have been using the `LoadFromDataTable` method to pop data from my entire dataset into one worksheet but not sure this is the right method for an iteration

What would I use while looping through my dataset so I can write data into the first sheet while evaluating the row value of the "location" field and then dynamically trigger new tabs/sheets as needed?

I am a new to C# and am teaching myself (basically starting the rebuild of my app with this one task of multi-tab excel exports) I am familiar with this type of looping in vb script in my classic .asp app.

Can anyone point me to an example of something like this in C# with dynamically spawned worksheets based on row values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CopytoDataTable to splt the data sets and create new worksheets

```
            var uniqueList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("ProdType")).Distinct();
            List<string> myList = new List<string>();
            myList = uniqueList.ToList();

            DataTable[] array = new DataTable[myList.Count()];
            int index = 0;
            foreach (string item in myList)
            {
                var Result = from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             where x.Field<string>("ProdType") == item
                             select x;
                DataTable table = Result.CopyToDataTable();
                array[index] = table;

                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(item);
                ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
                index++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.  If we talking about `DataTables` then one option would be the `DataTable.Select` [which you can read about here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Its a native function so that plus a for loop should work well.

I particularly like `Linq` because of its grouping ability. It will require you to learn the concepts of `Linq` which is not a bad thing but a little more reading on your part.  Only wrinkle is you will need to do some casting - not the end of the world since the data sets are relatively small generally :

```
[TestMethod]
public void Multi_Sheet_Export_Test()
{
    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col3", typeof (object))
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = i;
        row[1] = i*10;
        row[2] = i%2 == 0 ? "LocationX" : "LocationY";
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Create a test file
    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Multi_Sheet_Export.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
        fi.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var workbook = pck.Workbook;

        var colnames = new List<string[]>
        {
            datatable
                .Columns
                .Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Select(col => col.ColumnName)
                .ToArray()
        };


        var rowgroups = datatable
            .Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .GroupBy(row => row[2])
            .ToList();


        rowgroups.ForEach(rowgroup =>
        {
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(rowgroup.Key.ToString());
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromArrays(colnames);
            worksheet.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromArrays(rowgroup.Select(row => row.ItemArray));
        });

        pck.Save();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank Ernie.      I played with this for a while and wound up doing it like this: